# UIcollectionView not updating the size and layout of UIcollectionCell upon phone rotation

Tags: swift

I have a UIcollectionView with images.  When I rotate the screen, the cells do not resize as expected.  I have tried adding collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() to the viewDidLayoutSubviews() - but this only causes a crash.  Please can someone advise?

I have a UIcollectionView with images.  When I rotate the screen, the cells do not resize as expected.  I have tried adding collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() to the viewDidLayoutSubviews() - but this only causes a crash.  Please can someone advise?

Portrait:

[image]

Landdscape:

[image]

```
class GridPicksCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController{

let cellId = "gridyPickCell"
var numCelPerRow: CGFloat = 3
var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout!
let borderInset: CGFloat = 3
let interCellSpacing: CGFloat = 3
let spacingBetweenRows: CGFloat = 3
var dataSource = [UIImage]()
var collectionViewWidth: CGFloat!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    generalSetup()
    setUpDateSource()
    setupCollectionViewLayout()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")

    // Update collectionViewWidth upon rotation
    collectionViewWidth = self.collectionView.frame.width
    //collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout() - causes app to crash

}

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    print("viewWillTransition")
}


private func generalSetup(){
    navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.appDarkGreen
    navigationItem.title = "Girdy Picks"
    let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
    collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionViewWidth = collectionView.frame.width

    // Make sure collectionView is always within the safe area layout
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        collectionView?.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    }

    // Register UICollectionViewCell
    collectionView.register(GirdyPickCollectionCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}


private func setUpDateSource(){
    let images: [UIImage] = [UIImage.init(named: "buddha")!, UIImage.init(named: "sharpener")!,  UIImage.init(named: "cars")!, UIImage.init(named: "houses")!, UIImage.init(named: "houses2")!, UIImage.init(named: "tower1")!, UIImage.init(named: "tower2")!]
    dataSource = images

}

private func setupCollectionViewLayout(){
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = interCellSpacing // distance between cells in a row
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = spacingBetweenRows // distance in between rows
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: borderInset, left: borderInset, bottom: borderInset, right: borderInset) // border inset for collectionView
}
}


extension GridPicksCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataSource.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! GirdyPickCollectionCell
    cell.imageView.image = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedImage = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    let showImageVC = ImageGridViewController()
    showImageVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
    showImageVC.imageToDisplay = selectedImage
    self.present(showImageVC, animated: true) {}
}


// Determine size for UICollectionCell
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    print("sizeForItemAt")
    guard let collectionWidth = collectionViewWidth else{ return CGSize.init()}
    let widthCell = (collectionWidth - interCellSpacing * 2 - borderInset * 2) / numCelPerRow
    return CGSize.init(width: widthCell, height: widthCell)
}
}
```

Comment: You say "cells do not resize as expected" without saying what exactly is expected — while the layout actually seems legitimate.

Invalidating layout in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` causes a crash because you are forcing the layout into an infinite loop.

Comment: @WTEDST - what is expected is described in 'sizeForItemAt' . but as you can see the cells have not been resized as a result of the increase in the width of the screen.  Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong about your lifecycle of events. When the device is rotated, your view hierarchy becomes notified of this event, and views start to re-layout themselves based on the information they have. **After** this has been finished, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` will be called, not before.

Since you are updating the `collectionViewWidth` property in this method, the layout still uses the old value when calling `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`. You need to set this value in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()`.

Alternatively, you can write a setter for this property which will call `invalidateLayout()` on the collection view's layout, but this will cause an unnecessary layout pass.